# Image and video info, php

Tags: php, image, video

How can I get information about video and image file?

I need to get dpi, color profile for image extension *.jpg. Is it possible?
And information about video file:  fps, width_height,  bitrate.

Is it necessary for it install additional php extensions? I don't have this possibility to upgrade php config.

would be very grateful for  information.

Answer (score 0):

After a quick google search this seems to be what you are after: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

Answer (score 0):

for movie look this: http://getid3.sourceforge.net/

for image look this: http://sandalian.com/php/get-dpi-value-of-an-image-using-php.html

Answer (score 0):

Apart from http://getid3.sourceforge.net/. you can also use http://ffmpeg-php.sourceforge.net/, it supports more audio & video formats.